# Cannot get QueueList of the private message queue when tried to access it from remote machine

Tags: c#-4.0, msmq

When i am trying to get the private queue list from loacl machine using the code given below ,I am able to get the list of queue.

System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(String machineName)

But when i tried to access the queue list from the remote machine I am getting an error

Remote computer is not available.

I have access to the remote machine.

I have checked the permission of the queue and seems that it have full control.

Is there any else i need to check.I dont know what s the reason is.Will anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall setting in machine which you are trying to get queue list. It might be preventing the access of queue remotely.